# How to programmatically set error-page and etc web.xml parameters in spring

Tags: java, spring, web, configuration

I tired to set error-page parameter in `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer.onStartup` method.

I expect this is equivalent to:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/accessDenied.html</location>
</error-page>
```

I'm find class `StandardContext` that allow set error page via method `addErrorPage`. But i'm don't know how to get this class in `onStartup` method, or how to create new `StandardContext` and attach it to my app.

Perhaps, this is incorrect way, but i find only this. I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: You can find the details here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194724/custom-403-error-page-with-spring-security-configured-via-java-code

Comment: I'm alredy watch this link, but it unsuitable for any cases. 403 page is taken as an example. I'm want customize standart error page and for other error codes. For examle: i'm get request from any page and send response with error to the same page. And i'm see standart tomcat error page. I'm want change this.