# Programmatically set <error-page> using code rather than web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, custom-error-pages

I've seen:

[How to set session-timeout, error-pages programmatically without web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634281/how-to-set-session-timeout-error-pages-programmatically-without-web-xml)

and

[How to programmatically set error-page and etc web.xml parameters in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29075229/how-to-programmatically-set-error-page-and-etc-web-xml-parameters-in-spring)

The first one is however specific to tomcat, and the second has not a good answer, plus it requires Spring.

So is it possible to set the error-page normally defined in web.xml, maybe in an ServletListener or similar.

Comment: Use a servlet [`Filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to catch exception and/or check response status code, and redirect as needed.

Comment: @Andreas How would you do that? Set a filter mapped to `/*` and then?

Comment: @niklabaz Then write some code in the filter to "catch exception and/or check response status code, and redirect as needed". Which part of that in my original comment is unclear to you? How to "catch exception"? Use `try-catch` statement. How to "check response status code"? Use a `if` statement. How to "redirect"? Call [`forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward-javax.servlet.ServletRequest-javax.servlet.ServletResponse-) to redirect response generation to error page of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come across a similar requirement for my side project. I used custom unchecked exceptions that have status code and message fields.Eventually those fields will be used to set the HTTP status code and the message itself. I tested the project on embedded tomcat 9. Check my repository https://github.com/tugrulaslan/BankingAPI